# Proof related to open sets

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

How does one prove, using Zorn's Lemma, that every open set $G\subseteq R^n$ is the union of no more than countably many pairwise disjoint components?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why do you want to use Zorn's Lemma for this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose not. Then you can choose a different rational number ($q\in\mathbb Q^n$) from each of those components, and you would end up with an uncountble number of those!

AoC is being used to make sure you can choose one element each from those collections of uncountable components. AoC is equivalent to Zorn's Lemma.

Here is direct way to think about it if the given open set is bounded: The rational numbers ($q\in\mathbb Q^n$) from each of those components $X_a$ of the open set would be partially ordered w.r.t the natural order on $\mathbb R^n$, and each linearly ordered set $L\subset \mathbb Q^n\cap X_a$ would have a upper bound $x$ with $x_i=\sup y_i$  for $y\in L$. Hence, the rational numbers ($q\in\mathbb Q^n$) from each of those components of the open set would have a maximal element, which also must be unique. Now, this gives you an exact way to define the mapping used in the first paragraph.

Comment: Thanks! That edit about the AoC cleared things up. Very good explanation. Just give me five minutes before I can accept the answer!

Comment: I made the connection to ZL more explicit, hope it helps! Cheers  :)

Comment: The axiom of choice is not needed for this proof. It's a red herring.

Comment: @AsafKaragila If you explain it, I would be happy to edit my answer. Ex ante, it was not obvious how to specify a rule of choosing rationals from uncountable sets without AoC.

Comment: @Juanito Sorry to bother you again, but I am bothered by a point made by a friend: isn't it possible to create a pathological set that has no rational elements or elements of similar sets of numbers which one could use the AoC trick on? Thanks!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Shalom! I would welcome out of curiosity an answer not involving the AoC, and invite you to write it in!

Comment: Or in other words, your answer relies on a countable set that would be present in each of the components of our X, resulting in a contradiction if there are uncountably many components... Is there not a way to get around this by creating a special set?

Comment: When you said pairwise disjoint components, I assumed all of them are open themselves. Which means they must contain an interval, and hence rational points. What would be the point of making the pathological set? I guess it would not be open.

Comment: Ah, of course! You are quite right. They are all open subsets. Thanks for spending the time!